# How to make my iframe auto height adjust on host website?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, widget, disqus

I am creating web widgets and my customers embed them on their websites. 
The content in iFrame can be varied at runtime. How can I make my iframes auto-adjust their height just like disqus's comments thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are the owner of iframe, Its possible to establish communication between the iframe domain and the host domain. You can do that with following code

At host javascript

Sending message

```
ifrm.contentWindow.postMessage("someUniqueMessageId", "*");
```

receive message

```
window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
if (event.data.hasOwnProperty("someUniqueMessageId")) {
        var data = event.data.someUniqueMessageId;
    }
});
```

At iFrame javascript

```
window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
   if (event.data == "someUniqueMessageId") {
        var foo = 'bar'; // data you want to send to host
        event.source.postMessage({ "someUniqueMessageId": foo }, "*");
    }
});
```